# TextField With increment and decrement button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uicontrol, uipicker

[image]

I have to use a textfield which gets number as input along with two buttons to increment and decrement the number.

Is there something like this as shown in image?

I am thinking of using textfield with two buttons. But it will be not be good as I think.

Comment: This is not well suited to touch, the general rule-of-thumb is a minimum touch size of 44 X 44 points.Reliably touching the buttons in the image shown would be rather hit-and-miss at best. That is why such a control is not included in the set of controls provided by Apple.

Comment: Agree with Zaph. And I guess the image you have provided was made by a human that has nothing in common with designing IOS apps, otherwise he would make two separate buttons at least 30x30pt, OR an alternative input method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no control like that by default in iOS.

**Option1:** You have to create a component of yourself like what you have said. Create a component as AHPickerView(Ali Hassan PickerView)and you can give to the public(A UIView with a textfield and two buttons ) ;)

**Option2:** If you can sacrifice the UI then you can replicate the same functionality using UIPicker with two columns.

I prefer the second is option is good.

**Note:** Usability-wise option1 will be very hard for the user(Will almost irritate the user) to touch the increment and decrement button since it will be very small to touch exactly.

EDIT: AS @tc noted in comment, you may want to check this control [UIStepper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and its  [appearance here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIStepper.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIStepper)

Comment: Actually there (sort of) is: [UIStepper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (iOS 5.0+) has the buttons size-by-side. Of course, if there's a text field it might make sense to have the buttons on either side.

Comment: Oh yes that one is there. I almost forgot that one. Anyhow Ali has to tweak something to achieve his control. Again @tc thanks for nothing that. good catch ;)